# Having a 3 columns table with Latex

Tags: tables

Hello how can I get the same table as the picture with 3 columns : name, lastname, function using latex. This table is from Microsoft Word.
I would like to have dark blue : `#5530FF` for headers and this color : `#86D3FF` for alternative rows.

I would like the three columns be equally wide.

Here what I've tried :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=3cm,headheight=65pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage} 
\usepackage{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview = {XYZ null null 1.00}} 
\usepackage{csquotes}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

%HEADER <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark }
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-c}}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-c}}
%\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{blabla}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\thepage /\pageref{LastPage}}}  % added  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\fancyfoot[C]{\fbox{Confidential}} % added  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{sffamily}
            \begin{center}
                
                % Upper part of the page. The '~' is needed because \\
                % only works if a paragraph has started.
                \begin{figure}[th]
                    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}\hfill
                    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
                \end{figure}    
                \vspace{3cm}
                %  \textsc{\Large }\\[1.5cm]                    
                % Title
                \HRule \\[0.4cm]
                { \huge \bfseries blabla\\[0.4cm] }
                \HRule \\[1cm]
                %\includegraphics[width=12cm]{images/f5.png}                
                
                % Author and supervisor
                \Large  blabla\\
                \Large{blabla} \\
                \Large blabla\\[1cm]                
                
                \vspace{3cm}
                
                \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
                    \begin{flushleft} \large
                        \emph{\textbf{blabla}}\\ 
                        \textsc{blabla}\\
                        \textsc{blabla}\\
                    \end{flushleft}
                \end{minipage}
                ~
                \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
                    \begin{flushright} \large
                        \emph{\textbf{blabla}}\\
                        \textsc{blabla}\\
                        \textsc{blabla}\\
                    \end{flushright}
                \end{minipage}
                \vfill
                
                % Bottom of the page
                \vspace{1cm}
                {\large 2021 - 2022}
                
            \end{center}
        \end{sffamily}
    \end{titlepage}
    \newpage
    
    \section{blabka}
    \begin{tabular} {|>{\columncolor{#5530FF}}c|>{\columncolor{#86D3FF}}l|>{\columncolor{#86D3FF}}r|}

  \hline
  name & lastname & description l\\
  \hline
    text    &   text    &   text    \\
    text    &   text    &   text    \\
    text    &   text    &   text    \\
    text    &   text    &   text    \\
 \hline 
\end{tabular}  
   
    \vspace{-0.5cm}
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide some more information about the table's desired structure. E.g., should the table's width equal the full width, or some fixed fraction of the full width, of the text block? If its desired width is less than `\textwidth`, should be table be horizontally centered? Are the dark blue color for the header row and the alternating colors for the remaining rows essential? If so, which colors should be used? Should the three columns be equally wide? If not, please indicate your desired width ratios. Should automatic line wrapping be enabled in the third column?

Comment: Maybe you can start from https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-08?

Comment: I've update my question, I hope it's better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is type of "do this instead of me" (free of charge). That is not a way, how this site work ...

You should provide a MWE, which show, what is actually your problem. Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \begin{tblr}{hlines={blue}, vlines={blue},
                 colspec = {*{3}{X[l]}},
                 row{1}  = {c, font=\bfseries, fg=white, bg=blue},
                 row{even} = {bg=blue!10}
                 }
text    &   text    &   text    \\
text    &   text    &   text    \\
text    &   text    &   text    \\
text    &   text    &   text    \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which actually has no problems :-). And than describe, where you stuck in your effort ...

Comment: I've added my code as you said, event if ithe render is not what I want because it gives me 2 columns, the first one is all in dark blue and the second column is in light blue, but that's not what I want.

Comment: @Zokulko, are you test my MWE? Your document example far away from to be MWE ... BTW, you show it to late that I would be able to consider it in my answer.

Comment: No worries. Yes it works! Just a question if I want to have this time 4 columns , I've changed this line `colspec = {*{3}{X[l]}},` by `colspec = {*{4}{X[l]}},` but my content in my last column  goes beyond the cell. Do you see what do I have to change ?

Comment: Btw what `X` means inside the parenthesis please ?

Comment: @Zokulko, **(i)** consider coments below your question, **(ii)** beside given suggestion I suggest to read also https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables, **(iii)** for details how to use some particular package, in this case is `tabularray`, read package documentation. Column type `X[l]` means that column is of `X` type, similar as at `tabularx` package (its width is determined by LaTeX, it enables automatic breaking text in cells) and cells contents are left aligned.  Of course, for each column in a table should be defined (according to desired style of cell's style) type of column.

Comment: Is there a way to get three columns not equally wide (based on the content). I don't see this info on the docs please